# Slow mysql performance after moving to ipb

Tags: mysql, etl, database-migration, web-hosting, vbulletin

I recently moved from vbulletin to IPB and my current MySQL setup configuration seems to be having issues with it as the site suffers slow speeds. I am not sure which MySQL settings need to change to help with the load/speed.

The server is 2 x 2.4GHz Octa-Core E5-2630 v3 Haswell Xeon, Ram: 96 GB
Here is the result of mysqltuner.
Thank you

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WMo6SmHQ36QRnXGqwAPQSPGTpVbLwJDIqTe16U65LbA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The mysqltuner output suggests optimizing some tables. That often is a good idea after loading a table with imported data. Have you done that? Have you asked your software vendor (vbulletin) for help? How  about your hosting service (ipb)?  Your server machine is vast.

Comment: Thank you. we don't use vbulletin, we moved away from vbulletin to ipb (invasion power board). I already optimized the tables, converted all to innodb. but not sure what in MySQL config should be changed beyond what the tuner is suggesting.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS; 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post a replacement MySQLTuner report after minimum 24 hours of uptime since you are now almost all INNODB tables.

Comment: @virap After reviewing your 20121220 new MySQLTuner report, max_connections looks like it is limited to 80.  To avoid rejection of user connection attempts, consider 300 for max_connections because your 20201212 MST indicated you had 143 concurrent connections at some time during that 20 hours of uptime. Happy Holidays and Be Safe.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section based on data from MySQLTuner report and your question content.

```
connect_timeout=20  # from 10 to avoid aborted connections
thread_cache_size=100  # from ? to reduce threads_created of 143 in 20h
innodb_buffer_pool_size=36G  # from 10G to support all INNODB data and indexes
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 percent to support ETL activity
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
```

These 5 suggestions are just the beginning of configuation management opportunities.  View profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

wow, thank you so much. The above suggestions helped a lot with performance I think. Thank you so much, Wilson.

I know the hard drives are ssd, I don't think I have any NVME devices.

Here is the information you asked. Thank you very much in advance.

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS: https://pastebin.com/qsxL4TKV


SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/y4iGazLZ


SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST: https://pastebin.com/kJ2pcNQ2


STATUS: https://pastebin.com/7DTq76hV


SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS: https://pastebin.com/dNWZ9EaV


ulimit: https://pastebin.com/9B93EXS7


iostat: https://pastebin.com/hs7WDgq9


top: https://pastebin.com/nXshBwR0 


mysqltuner: https://pastebin.com/9Ff4kKKh
```

Comment: Thank you I could not find the script you refer to. I checked your website and the price lists and unfortunately, at this time I can't afford it.

Comment: On our site, on the top row you should see Home, What We Do, Data We Need, Example Suggestions, Shop Analysis Services, Referrals, FAQ, "Utility Scripts" where you will find our free downloadable Utility Scripts. Get in touch, please.